# How do I import an .ical file into Outlook 365 (online version of Outlook)

Tags: office365, outlook-web-access

I import ical files into my google calendar all the time (this is my personal calendar)

At work I use Outlook365 (on line version). I cannot see how to import .ical files.

I am using the newest Outlook365 GUI, and the "New Calendar" option appears to be MIA?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Classic Outlook Web Access

You can import `.ical` files into Outlook Web Access by:

1. Click the Calendar button in the bottom left corner.

[image: Navigation Bar]

2. At the top of the page, click **Add calendar**, then **From file**.

[image: Calendar view with Add Calendar and From file highlighted]

3. Browse for your `.ical` file and select the calendar you would like to import it into.

[image: Import screen]

## Outlook Web Access Beta View

You can import `.ical` files into Outlook Web Access by:

1. Click the Calendar button in the bottom left corner.

[image: Navigation Bar]

2. In the Calendar sidebar, click **Discover calendars**

[image: Discover calendars in the Calendar sidebar]

3. Click **From file**, browse for your `.ical` file and select the calendar you would like to import it into.

[image: Import from file]

Comment: Thanks!  I do not see the "Add Calendar" option in my UI.  OP enhanced.

Comment: @SamJones Take a look at my edit for instructions on doing this in the Beta View.

Comment: That works! Thanks!  It should say ".ics or .ical file" but whatev, it worked. Thanks!